# how to install google play services programmatically in android for displaying google maps ?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a device in which google play services are not installed. My application uses google maps to display current location..So in order to display maps i am getting a message to install google play services.

I have code to check whether google play services is installed or not.
final int RQS_GooglePlayServices = 1;

```
// Check status of Google Play Services
int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

// Check Google Play Service Available
try {
    if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, RQS_GooglePlayServices).show();
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("Error: GooglePlayServiceUtil: ", "" + e);
}
```

But it just displays another dialog to install google play services..On click of the button it says NO SCAN DATA Received.
Can any one help me to install play services programmatically...or should i just manually install them ...?

Answer (score 0):

If your device legitimately has the Play Store on it, the dialogs should help the user get over to the Play Store to download the appropriate APK. If that is not working, make sure you are on the latest Play Services SDK.

If your device does not have the Play Store on it, or it has a pirated copy (whether pirated by you or the device manufacturer), then there is no legitimate way for the user to get the Play Services Framework, and that would explain why the dialogs are not working. If you are planning on distributing through channels other than the Play Store, you need to use an alternative source of maps for those channels (e.g., OpenStreetMap).

Comment: i dont have play store in my device...so i manually installed by downloading play store apk...but it is not working...play store is not opening..my device is an Aratek device which has android os

Comment: @user9213: Then you need to use some other map solution other than Maps V2 from the Play Services SDK.